# Strange behavior on JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, if-statement, return-value

I'm working on JavaScript code to get the string of the correct image to show but is not working, I'get an empty string on the las console log.

```
function jsmBatteryLevelIMG(lvl)
{
var icono ="";
      console.log(lvl);

       if(lvl < 3.60) {
           icono= "/track/images/Batt000.png";
           console.log("000");
       } 
       else if(lvl <= 3.60) {
           console.log("025");
           icono= "/track/images/Batt025.png";
       }
console.log(icono); //<---Empty string ???
return icono;
};
```

But if I do

```
function jsmBatteryLevelIMG(lvl)
{
    var icono ="";
    console.log(lvl);
    icono= "/track/images/Batt025.png";
    console.log(icono); //<---Not empty string ???
    return icono;
};
```

it works OK.

What I'm missing?

**Edit:**

I tried this code

```
 function jsmBatteryLevelIMG(lvl)
 {
 var icono ="";
         console.log(lvl);

         if(lvl < 3.60) {
             icono= "/images/Batt000.png";
             console.log("001");
         } 
         else {
             console.log("026");
             icono= "/images/Batt025.png";
         }
 console.log(icono);
 return icono;

 };
```

Now I get a value in the variable icono but did not work as the second code that I write before.

Comment: `Icono` is not the same variable name as `icono`.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, I make a mistake tipyng the code. The real code have one variable icono.

Comment: Is `lvl` greater than `3.6`? Should your first condition read `lvl > 3.6` instead?

Comment: what is the value of lvl?

Comment: You're checking to see if it's less than 3.60, then checking to see if it's less than or equal to 3.60. What if it's greater?

Comment: Well what if `lvl` is `3.61`?  Your `if` statements leave open the possibility that neither the `if` part nor the `else` part will run. Have you added `console.log(lvl)` to see that value?

Comment: I suspect `<= 3.60` is a typo for `>= 3.60`. But you don't need that test, just use `else`, since it's the opposite of the first test.

Comment: I have a fixed value of 3.6 on the database

Comment: add an `else` to the end. probably neither `if` is firing

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Javascript is a *case-sensitive* language.

Your references to `Icono` and `icono` are **not** equivalent.

You've since updated the source to change this, so it should now be apparent that, in the second example, icono is now reflecting the direct assignment it was given before the console.log() call.

In the first example, icono could be blank if lvl>3.60.

Answer (score 0):

Ehat is the value of `lvl`? Your code only handles 3.6 and below so `icono` doesn't get set a value `if (lvl > 3.6)`. You probably mean:

```
function jsmBatteryLevelIMG(lvl)   
{  
    var icono = "";

    if(lvl < 3.60) {
       icono = "/track/images/Batt000.png";
    } 
    else if(lvl <= 7.20) {
       icono = "/track/images/Batt025.png";
    } 
    else if(level <= 10.8) {
       icono = "/track/images/Batt075.png";
    }
    else {
       icono = "/track/images/Batt100.png"
    }
    return icono;
};
```

Comment: The actual value is 3.6 because I'm debugging but I must handle values from 3.5 (0%) to 4.3(100% of battery).